# Grid Image Not Showing properly

Tags: order-grid

I have used below code for Grid Products Image in shopping cart tab, Its showing same image in all products, Please help , Kindly check attached snap-shot for more detail.

---

```
$this->addColumn('Image', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
        'type'  => 'image',
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'image',
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image')

    ));

public function callback_image()
{

          $_productCollection = $this->getCollection();
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
        $product_id = $_product->getProductId();
    }
    if(isset($product_id)){
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
        $smallImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getSmallImage());
        $width = 70;
        $height = 70;
        return "<img src='".$smallImageUrl."' width=".$width." height=".$height."/>";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to first verify that, you get proper $product_id in your function. I think It return same Id every call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->addColumn('Image', array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
    'type'  => 'image',
    'width' => '100px',
    'index' => 'image',
    'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red',

));
```

And make a class file (You can make your own class file in your module and use that path)

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
      public function render(Varien_Object $row)
      {
    $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product/'
    $productId =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $smallImageUrl = $imageUrl.$product->getSmallImage();
    $width = 70;
    $height = 70;
    return "<img src='".$smallImageUrl."' width=".$width." height=".$height."/>";


      }
}
```

Comment: But, What's the Wrong with my code, can u please check

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getMediaUrl() on null in /home/mysticex/public_html/testinter/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/Red.php on line 8                           i am getting this Error

Comment: Check updated answer